# Multi-threading for loops with OpenMP

Tags: gcc, openmp

I am trying use openmp for multi-threading. It is pretty easy to do so for code that look as follows

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n)
    for (int m = 0; m < 20; ++n)
```

How about code that have the following structure:

```
int test, z;
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
    test = 3 * n;
    for (int m = 0; m < 20; ++n) {
        z = test * m;
    }
}
```

`#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` won't work here because of the line `test = 3 * n;` before the inner loop.

Comment: @SeanBright sorry i edited it

Answer (score 0):

So replace

```
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
    test = 3 * n;
    for (int m = 0; m < 20; ++n) {
        z = test * m;
    }
}
```

with

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 20; ++n) {
        z = 3 * n * m;
    }
}
```

The more general point, which may apply to your real code (I'm sure what you've posted is a much-simplified version of your real code), is that code can often be rewritten to enable 'easy' parallelisation.  It takes a bit of thought though.